# EF5 TPH Extra Foreign Keys being generated - How to get rid of them?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, table-per-type, table-per-hierarchy

This is a sample app I've concocted which produces the same behaviour as my actual much-more-complex app.
I'm obviously missing some configuration aspect somewhere, but can't figure it out for the life of me.  For some reason, each collection in my KID class is receiving its' own field and foreign key in the Sweet table....which just isn't necessary as far as I can see.....?
How can I stop EF generating these?

Example classes, config and resulting migration code follows (NB, If I use TPT instead of TPH the extra fields aren't added and OwnerId is used as the relational field just fine)

My classes:

```
    public class Sweet
    {
        [Key]
        public int SweetId { get; set; }
        public string SweetName { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
        public Kid Owner { get; set; }
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    }
    public class Chocolate : Sweet {}
    public class HardBoiled : Sweet {}
    public class Chewy : Sweet {}

    public class Kid
    {
        public int KidId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Chocolate> Chocolates { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<HardBoiled> BaggedSweeets { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Chewy> PacketSweets { get; set; }
    }
```

My Configuration (Called from OnModelCreating)

```
public class SweetConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Sweet>
{
    public SweetConfiguration()
    {
        Map(m => m.ToTable("Sweet"));

        Map<Chocolate>(i => i.Requires("SweetType").HasValue(1));

        Map<Chewy>(i => i.Requires("SweetType").HasValue(2));

        Map<HardBoiled>(f => f.Requires("SweetType").HasValue(3));
    }
}
```

The generated Migration code:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Kid",
            c => new
                {
                    KidId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    FirstName = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.KidId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Sweet",
            c => new
                {
                    SweetId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    SweetName = c.String(),
                    OwnerId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Kid_KidId = c.Int(), <--- DON'T NEED THIS
                    Kid_KidId1 = c.Int(), <--- OR THIS
                    Kid_KidId2 = c.Int(), <-- OR THIS!
                    SweetType = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.SweetId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Kid", t => t.Kid_KidId)  <!-- LIKEWISE FOR THESE THREE KEYS
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Kid", t => t.Kid_KidId1)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Kid", t => t.Kid_KidId2)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Kid", t => t.OwnerId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Kid_KidId)
            .Index(t => t.Kid_KidId1)
            .Index(t => t.Kid_KidId2)
            .Index(t => t.OwnerId);

    }
```

UPDATE:

As it would appear my current model isn't supported I have changed my Kid class like this:

```
public class Kid
{
    public int KidId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Sweet> Sweets { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<HardBoiled> BaggedSweets
    {
        get
        {
            return Sweets.OfType<HardBoiled>().ToList();
        }
    }
    ... and two more read-only NotMapped properties for the other collections...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use three collections in this model. EF expects that the inverse property and FK property (`Owner` and `OwnerId`) are *declared* directly in the classes the collections are refering to (i.e. in `Chocolate`, `HardBoiled` and `Chewy`) and not in the base class. To make it work and have only a single foreign key you can only define a single navigation collection in `Kid` that refers to the base class where `Owner` and `OwnerId` are declared in:

```
public class Kid
{
    public int KidId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Sweet> Sweets { get; set; }
}
```

(You can btw extract specific types from this collection using `Sweets.OfType<Chocolate>()`, etc.)

This is also the case for TPT. Is it possible that you had no `SweetConfiguration` and no `DbSet<Sweet>` in your TPT test? This would result in a model with no inheritance at all (from EF viewpoint) because all properties of the base class `Sweet` would have been added into the three child tables.

Comment: In my actual code Sweet is an abstract class, so I don't use it anywhere - but I see your point about no inheritance.
Is this problem EF specific? Can other ORM's cope with this type of model?

Comment: @DaveR: I don't know if other ORMs can map these classes like you want to map them. Using a single `Sweets` collection is not a big loss in my opinion because you can always filter the child classes out of the collection. If you want, even with three additional (not mapped) readonly properties (only with a getter) in `Kid` that return `Sweets.OfType<Chocolate>()` as `IEnumerable<Chocolate>`, etc.

Comment: Yes.  Already edited my answer to show how I did this.  Thanks for clarifying.